# persistant 403 error even with no htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I made a directory secure via htacces and htpasswd.

Then I wanted to take off the password, so I deleted the .ht* files, and now it's throwing up 403 errors.

I have cleared cashe and tried to open it on multiple other machines, still 403's.

Why is it restricting my directory even while the .ht* files have all been deleted???

Comment: It works properly on my localhost, does that mean it's something to do with my hosting provider?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had numbers being posted as php variables, which worked on my localhost but not when I uploaded.

Solution: Use variables that start with a letter. 'a2' instead of '2'.